# Disable completion cache in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a script which can complete itself when called with `complete` arg. Following Zsh completion script transferring it to Zsh:

```
#compdef das

_das() {
        local -a commands
        self="$(echo $words | cut -d' ' -f1)"
        numargs=$(($CURRENT-2))
        if [ $numargs -ge 1 ]; then
                args=$(echo ${words#$self} | xargs | cut -d' ' -f-$numargs)
        fi
        $self complete $(echo ${args}) | while read line; do
                commands+=("$line")
        done
        _describe -t commands 'commands' commands
        return 0
}

_das
```

It works well, but after first entered command Zsh remembers last completion it showed and shows only it, without calling `$self complete` again.
How to force it to call script every time, not only first?

Comment: I am also trying to find this out. Bash does not seem to do this caching while zsh does. This makes zsh kinda annoying when using nixos or nixpkgs. I have been looking for options to control it but don't see any. I also looked for an option to make bash act like zsh here and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

To force Zsh to call the completion script every time instead of only the first time, you can add the -r option to the _describe command in your script. This option causes Zsh to reset the completion system so that it will call your script again for the next completion request

```
_describe -r -t commands 'commands' commands
```